"linkage specification is incompatible with previous" error E0337 and "undeclared identifier" error C2065 when trying to call functions from a DLL
My goal is to create a DLL which allows me to read data from a Beckhoff PLC program via ADS. For this I have created a DLL and a test program. Within the DLL I use the TcAdsDll from Beckhoff and a specially created class which contains all the required functions and data types. The DLL compiles without an error message. When compiling my test program by calling the functions of the DLL, I get the errors:
>E0337  linkage specification is incompatible with previous "AdsAmsPortEnabled" (declared at line 143)  famosAdsTestEnvironment C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\Include\TcAdsAPI.h   
Error (active)  E0067   expected a '}'  famosAdsTestEnvironment C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\Include\TcAdsAPI.h       
Error   C2065   'NULL': undeclared identifier   famosAdsTestEnvironment C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\Include\TcAdsDef.h   
Error   C2065   'BOOL': undeclared identifier   famosAdsTestEnvironment C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\Include\TcAdsAPI.h   
Error   C2065   'pbEnabled': undeclared identifier  famosAdsTestEnvironment C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\Include\TcAdsAPI.h   
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'BOOL' famosAdsTestEnvironment C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\Include\TcAdsAPI.h   

Clicking on all errors takes me to the read-only header file of the ADS-Dll from Beckhoff. I have already been able to find out using the search function that an error has probably occurred when including the header files. However, I cannot find it,
Below is my written code
Dll Headerfile
#pragma once
#include "C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\Include\TcAdsDef.h"
#include "C:\TwinCAT\AdsApi\TcAdsDll\Include\TcAdsAPI.h"


#ifdef FAMOSADSLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define FAMOSADSLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define FAMOSADSLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif 

class FAMOSADSLIBRARY_API adsCommunication {
private:
long      nErr, nPort = 0;
AmsAddr   Addr;
PAmsAddr  pAddr = &Addr;
int       adress;
int       datatyp;

public:

adsCommunication(int datatyp = 0x4, int adress = 0x0) {
    this->datatyp = datatyp;
    this->adress = adress;

}

void connectADS();
void disconnectADS();
float readADS();
void writeADS(int data);
};

Dll Main
#include "pch.h"
#include "famosAdsLibrary.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "framework.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                   DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                   LPVOID lpReserved
                 )
{
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
}
return TRUE;
}

void adsCommunication::connectADS() {

// Open communication port on the ADS router
nPort = AdsPortOpen();
nErr = AdsGetLocalAddress(pAddr);
if (nErr) cerr << "Error: AdsGetLocalAddress: " << nErr << '\n';
pAddr->port = 851;

}

float adsCommunication::readADS() {
INT data = 0;
nErr = AdsSyncReadReq(pAddr, 0x4020, adress, datatyp, &data);
if (nErr) cerr << "Error: AdsSyncReadReq: " << nErr << '\n';
cout << data << endl;
return data;
}

void adsCommunication::writeADS(int data) {

nErr = AdsSyncWriteReq(pAddr, 0x4020, adress, datatyp, &data);
if (nErr) cerr << "Error: AdsSyncWriteReq: " << nErr << '\n';
}


void adsCommunication::disconnectADS() {
nErr = AdsPortClose();
if (nErr) cerr << "Error: AdsPortClose: " << nErr << '\n';
}

Testprogram Headerfile
#pragma once

#include <famosAdsLibrary.h>
#include <Windows.h>

Testprogram Main
#include "Main.h"


int main() {

int       value = 0;

adsCommunication data(0x4, 0x0);

data.connectADS();

while (1)
{
    value = data.readADS();

    if (value >= 800) {

        value = 0;

        data.writeADS(wert);
    }
}

data.disconnectADS();


system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}

Below are the errors in the read-only code of the Beckhoff header files
#ifndef __ADSAPI_H__
#define __ADSAPI_H__

#define ADSAPIERR_NOERROR           0x0000
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

//other dllexports without error


__declspec( dllexport )
long __stdcall AdsAmsPortEnabled(BOOL *pbEnabled);

// more dllexports without error
__declspec( dllexport )
long __stdcall AdsAmsPortEnabledEx(long nPort, BOOL *pbEnabled);

Thanks for your help

The errors are in a file TcAdsAPI.h but you haven't posted the contents of that file. So it's kind of hard to know what the error might be. I imagine the error is some macro or other that you are expected to define, but without seeing the code it's impossible to even guess what that might be. Please edit the question to include the code that is causing your errors.

I have edited my question and inserted the code snippets that cause the errors in TcAdsAPI.h

So there seem to be two issues. The first is that your function AdsAmsPortEnabled is unconditionally declared as an dllexport. That's correct when you are building the DLL, it's not correct when you are building code that uses the DLL. That seems to be what is causing the first error (about linkage specification)

The second error is that the function declaration uses the type BOOL. That type is defined in windows.h but it seems that windows.h has not been included at this point. So the answer to that error is to make sure that you include windows.h before you include TcAdsAPI.h

@john Inlcuding Windows.h first solved the problem. I was able to fix the linker error. Many thanks for your help

In Testprogram.h swap #include <famosAdsLibrary.h> and #include <Windows.h> fixed my problem.
